# Reading data from Firebase takes long even with small dataset

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am currently using Firebase as a backend storage and want to retrieve a set of data.

Using [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) I am getting the data and adapting it as a list.

At first I thought that the issue was with the dataset but after reducing the dataset to just two json objects made out of a few simple strings the issue persists.

The below is the code used to retrieve the data.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.child("events/");    
Log.d("TST", "Before Firebase");

//ListAdapter eventListAdapter;
upcomingEventsList.setAdapter(new FirebaseListAdapter<EventListModel>(getActivity(), EventListModel.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, myRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, EventListModel model, int position) {
                Log.d("TST", "After Firebase");
            }
        });
```

The below is the run messages given with the time for the relevant messages.

```
**01-10 23:18:25.113** D/TST: Before Firebase
I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1....020_msm8960_LA.AF.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
              OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
              Build Date: 05/22/15 Fri
              Local Branch: mybranch10237523
              Remote Branch: quic/LA.AF.1.1_rb1.18
              Local Patches: NONE
              Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020.....NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1f008d67 time:914885804
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1b48d3c0 time:914885804
**01-10 23:18:28.283** D/TST: After Firebase
**01-10 23:18:28.283** D/TST: After Firebase
```

Is this loss of approx. 3.5s normal or am I doing something wrong?

Why is the populateView method accessed twice not once (shown according to 2 *TST: After Firebase* messages)?

Dataset being retrieved in the above example is two of the below data object:

```
{end_date=1476835200, 
 title=Test, location=Test, content=Test, 
 start_date=1476835200, featured_image=Test,
 categories=[festivals, music]}
```

**Edit to answer Frank's question**

Second connection takes significantly less, tried with both the same dataset and a new dataset.

```
01-11 01:28:37.248 30667-30667/madebyhangar.valletta2018 D/TST: Before Firebase (before retrieval starts)
01-11 01:28:41.245 30667-30667/madebyhangar.valletta2018 D/TST: After Firebase (first retrieval finished)
01-11 01:28:41.350 30667-30667/madebyhangar.valletta2018 D/TST: SECOND PROCESS: After Firebase (second retrieval finished)
```

Comment: I don't know if this would change anything but the `/` in `.child("events/")` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you have ever used the above methods could you give me some feedback on whether this is actually considered as slow or not?

Comment: What happens if you try doing this with a query instead of a DatabaseReference? For example just add `.limitToFirst(10)` to the `myRef` which is the 4th parameter on your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: Nothing changed virtually same time taken for it to process. Can this be an issue regarding authentication, as I'm currently bypassing it by opening the database connection?

Comment: Could be but I have to be honest: I do not know. I authenticate users and it works really fast, but I'm not sure if this would change anything. Going to upvote your question as I'm really interested in any provided answer. Hope Frank van Puffelen sees this..

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Making the initial connection can take some time. 3.5 seconds seems longer than usual, but that could depend on many factors (latency, bandwidth, data size, hops, etc). I'd be more interested if the subsequent loads also take long, since those are going over the already established connection.

Comment: Hi Frank see results above, I have tried more than one dataset with similar results. It seems that the problem is the first retrieval.

Comment: If the slowness only happens on the first retrieval, it is the establishing of the connection that is slow. There are a lot of variables in there to troubleshoot, so I'm not sure what help we can offer here. The only way to improve it is likely to switch to a different network (or potentially change network settings), which has nothing to do with your Firebase-using code.

Comment: As for my experience with similar problem. I noticed that loading data for the first time always takes longer because every other time you just pull the data from cache. Also it depends on the structure of the database. When I tried loading the data that is too big or there is a lot of nested objects it took significantly more time rather than trying to load small data that is flat.